# Launch Script for Windows7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, powershell, application-launch

Hey guys hopefully I can thoroughly explain what I'm trying to do here! LOL

I have a dual display Windows 7 PC and what I am trying to do is launch 2 different programs on boot, and I want one to launch on one display, and the other to launch on the other display. I have been told that I need a script written to do exactly what I'm trying to do!

I got both the programs to launch with the code below, but I don't know how to tell each line to execute on a particular monitor.

Any help with this would be awesome!!!

start /d "C:\Program Files\Survey" SURVEY.EXE

start /d "C:\Program Files\Survey2" SURVEY2.EXE

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are not able to recode the applications so that they remember the screen that they were started on?

If not, I would wrap the startup in a script using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). This has macro commands that allow you to move Windows to another monitor.

Comment: No I can't and I can get them to launch on separate displays right now, but I need a script written to do this because the system needs to start this way.

I want these apps. to launch on boot, on the proper display. 

I had this done before with a web based program I had, and it worked great.....

Comment: Here is the script....

Comment: set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
  
     Dim objExplorer : Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
     objExplorer.navigate "//localhost/iconplayer/" 
    
     objExplorer.Left = -1024
     objExplorer.Top = 0 
     
     objExplorer.Visible = True 
     objExplorer.FullScreen = true

Comment: Do 
' Wait till the Browser is loaded 
Loop Until objExplorer.readyState = 4   

     set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
  
     Dim objExplorer2 : Set objExplorer2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
     objExplorer2.navigate "//localhost/iconplayer/" 
    
     objExplorer2.Left = 0 
     objExplorer2.Top = 0 
     
     objExplorer2.Visible = True 
     objExplorer2.FullScreen = true

Comment: Do 
' Wait till the Browser is loaded 
Loop Until objExplorer.readyState = 4

Comment: @Chris please update your question with this script, so others can easily see this information and offer help.

Comment: @Chris, you can certainly do that with AutoHotKey. You can also compile AHK scripts to executables.